# How to show available time more precisely?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

so i have booking software in clinic, so operators can put on which time someone is booked and etc, i also have website where customers can book online, basically this is what i made for website which checks what time is available for customer to see on website

```
 $sql_ebook = "SELECT TOP (1000) [IdVisitor], [Data], [DataEnd], [IdWorker] FROM [BServices].[dbo].[booking] WHERE (Data BETWEEN '$tdate' AND '$edate')";
  $qq = array();
  if(($result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql_booking)) !== false){
    while( $ss = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result )) {
      $ss = (array) $ss;
      $ssData = (array) $ss['Data'];
      $ssData = date_format(date_create($ssData['date']), "H:i");
      $ssEnd = (array) $ss['DataEnd'];
      $ssEnd = date_format(date_create($ssEnd['date']), "H:i");
     
      $ii = $ssData[0].$ssData[1];
      for(;$ii<$ssEnd[0].$ssEnd[1];$ii++){
        if(strlen($ii) == 1) $ii = '0'.$ii;
        $qq[$ss['IdTanam']][] = $ii.":00";
    }
  }
```

so, it works good, if operator books for example someone for 2 hours, website will not show those 2 hours as available on the websites booking form. like this :

[image: here it shows that user cant book from 15:00 to 18:00 (120 minutes)]

so problem which i have right now is this : customer from website gets time booked for 45 minutes, but my website will not show, for example if customer booked at 12:00 clock, and on sql [Data] is 12:00 and [DataEnd] is 12:45, website will still show that from 12:00 to 13:00 booking is available, can i know why? or where i have mistake ? if i will change 45 minutes to 1 hour then it will show that from 12:00 to 13:00 booking is not available. i want to show that its not possible for 45 minutes, and also enable customers to book available 15 minutes per in that range. everything listed above is from visittime.js
p.s.s here is the booking form's js functionality which recalls time from above visttime.js

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
var firstDate = $('#form_date').val();
getDates(firstDate);



$('#form_date, #form_team').change(function() {
  $('#form_timeFrom').text('');
  var dDate = $('#form_date').val();
  getDates(dDate);
});

function getWorkingTimes(){
                for(var cc=10, bb=20;cc<bb;cc++){
                  if(cc.toString().length == 1) cc = '0' + cc;
                  $('#form_timeFrom').append('<option value="'+cc+':00">'+cc+':00</option>');
                }
}

function getRange(range){
              $('#form_timeFrom').text('');
                for(var cc=10, bb=20;cc<bb;cc++){
                  if($.inArray(cc+":00", range) < 0){
                    if(cc.toString().length == 1) cc = '0' + cc;
                    $('#form_timeFrom').append('<option value="'+cc+':00">'+cc+':00</option>');
                  }
                }
}

function getDates(sdate){
        $.get("<?=$url?>assets/js/visitTime.php?date="+sdate, function( data ) {

          var data = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

          if(data != undefined){
            var firstKey = $('#form_team').find("option:selected").val();
            var range = data.timeRange[firstKey];
            if(range != undefined){

              getRange(range);

            } else getWorkingTimes();
          } else getWorkingTimes();
        });
}

    </script>
```

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a browser-side JS problem, or a server-side PHP problem?

Comment: i think its not a "problem" its logics mistake somewhere